# Why is my mousedown subscription getting triggered when no new mousedown events have happened since my subscription was set?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, mousedown

In my Angular app, I have a function that gets called by the `(mousedown)` output event on a <kbd>Click Me</kbd> button. The function contains code that subscribes to **future** `mousedown` events.

However, strangely, the subscription is firing even **before** any other mousedown event happens.

I've created a [Stackblitz to demonstrate](https://rxjs-mousedown2.stackblitz.io/) (+ [source code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-mousedown)), but here is the code pasted here:

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";
  output = '';

  performActionOnClick() {
    console.log("Action [1] Performed!");
    this.output += "\nAction [1] Performed!";

    fromEvent<MouseEvent>(document, "mousedown").subscribe(
      this.performActionOnTrigger.bind(this)
    );
  }

  performActionOnTrigger() {.                      <------ this function gets called despite
    console.log("Action [2] Performed!");                  only one mouse click !
    this.output += "\nAction [2] Performed!";
  }
}
```

**Why is this function getting called after only a single mouse click** ?

Comment: It's caused by event bubbling mechanism

Answer (score 1):

As commented by Teedeez, the reason this is happening is because of "bubbling" or event propegation.

The mouse event is triggered first on the innermost element, your button, but then it is triggered on the parent and it's parent etc all the way up to the window.

Read more here:

https://www.sitepoint.com/event-bubbling-javascript/

You may have to rethink your event listener to account for this, or you can specify in the event that it not propegate.

Comment: Ok, but doesn't all the bubbling stuff happen BEFORE my code reaches the point where it sets the `fromEvent` ?